# log4cplus: Dynamic loading configuration script, how to solve this problem?

Tags: c++, log4cplus

when I use "ConfigureAndWatchThread" in main function, it's work

```
int main()
{
    ......
    Logger root = Logger::getRoot();
    log4cplus::ConfigureAndWatchThread configureThread("log4cplus.properties", 1 * 1000);
    ......
}
```

buf, if I use "ConfigureAndWatchThread" in other function, dynamic load configure doesn't work! codes as follow:

```
void b()
{
    ConfigureAndWatchThread configureThread("log4cplus.properties", 5 * 1000);
}
void a()
{
    b();
}

int main()
{
    ......
    Logger root = Logger::getRoot();
    a();
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic variable lifetime issue. The `configureThread` variable goes out of scope in `b()` and that kills the whole thread that is watching for configuration changes. While, when you have it in `main()`, it stays alive as long as you do not exit `main()` which is for the entirety of your application run time.

Comment: Thx, solved, I got it, I'm so sorry for this stupid mistake!